# pass one value less to function i see a mismatch and returns NAN

Tags: javascript

Why is this function returning NaN?

```js
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
//add(10);

var result = add(10);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Try `add('10')`.

Comment: well b is undefined... What do you think should happen?

Comment: @RobG why try pass it as a string, you will still get `10undefined` in the return as no second argument is given

Comment: @all I tried and posted, but still negative :( should I not post this questions if I dont find solutions ??

Comment: What do you expect a solution to be when your code expects two arguments and you pass it one?

Comment: @texirv **nfn neil**'s answer explains why you're getting the result `NaN` It's hard to give you working source code without knowing the expected output or the use of `b` since your source code doesn't attempt to pass `b` in the function call so the answers and comments given so far are the best you can get for the information we have for this question. *"Apart from RobG's comment which is still wrong and will return undefined as explained above"*

Comment: @NewToJS—exactly, so the OP realises that *b* is undefined. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` is undefined when you only pass `10` to the function, thus 10 + undefined is what you're returning; so `NaN`, aka Not a Number.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `b` is `undefined`. Therefore, in your addition, JavaScript tries to coerce `undefined` to a number. The result of this coercion is always `NaN`:

```js
console.log(+undefined);
console.log(parseInt(undefined));
console.log(Number(undefined));
```

And of course, a number + `NaN` always gives you `NaN`:

```js
console.log(1 + NaN);
console.log(NaN + 1);
```

If you want to restrict this permissive behavior of JavaScript, you could **use default parameters** and/or **throw custom errors**:

```js
function add(a, b) {
  a = a || 0;
  b = b || 0;
  return a + b;
}

var result = add(10);

console.log(result);
```

```js
function add(a, b) {
  if (typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number') {
    if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
      throw new Error('NaN is not a number');
    } else {
      return a + b;
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error('Invalid operands');
  }
}

var result = add(10);

console.log(result);
```

**Currying** could also be considered:

```js
function add(a) {
  return function (b) {
    return a + b;
  };
}

console.log(add(10));
console.log(add(10)(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
//add(10);

var result = add(10,0);
//change this

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer. Only post the code is not a good an answer.